# Multiple LINQ Where vs foreach on List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

If I have a collection:

```
List<T> collection;
```

and I need to perform two test on this collection, which is more efficient:

```
foreach(T t in collection.where(w => w.value == true))
{
     t.something = true;
}

foreach(T t in collection.where(w => w.value2 == true))
{
     t.something2 = true;
}
```

Or

```
foreach(T t in collection)
{
 if (t.value == true)
  {
     //check 1
  }

  if (t.value2 == true)
  {
    //check 2
  }
}
```

I think it'll be the later because I presume that each `where` will iterate the collection but just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something?

Comment: strictly speaking, it is the `foreach` that iterates. The `Where` just sets up a filtered (but non-iterated) wrapper.

Comment: You could also use the `Any`-extension: `t.something = collection.Any(w => w.value);`, though that test only one of the collections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might change according the collection size. However I would go with the second code.

The first code iterates the entire collection twice (one per `where`) and then iterates each result once.

The second code iterates just once the entire collection. Also, it's cleaner.

Comment: Talking around 100-200 records.

Comment: Also note, that the second code is far better especially in case your data source is an IEnumerable.

Comment: Haven't thought, very true!

Answer (score 3):

The second will most likely be slightly faster, but the difference is quite small.

What might be more important is that you do things in a different order. The first code loops through all items acting on one condition first, then again acting on the other condition. The second code loops through the items once, checking both conditions for each item in turn. Depending on what you are doing with the items, that may make a difference.

Comment: I'm simply setting to separate boolean flags.

Answer (score 2):

First case enumerates your collection twice (using `WhereEnumerator` to do the check for you), the second only once, but you have to do your check manually. The latter case would be more efficient also because you use simple conditional expression to compare the item value, while the `WhereEnumerator` has to call the supplied delegate on each item.